# PHP - MySQL - AJAX and Google chrome - Endless loop responses and other errors

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-chrome

I'm making a user registration form in PHP - MYSQL, AJAX jQuery and Codeigniter and loading the web page of records, Google chrome console launches a series of unlimited answers every second, the image here.

[image]

**Note:** There are also some slightly unusual behavior in Google Chrome I want to know the reason to solve them.

**Selection in yellow:** the answers are automatically generated limitless.

**Selection in purple:** Are the result or answer to that selected answer.

**Selection Green:** Other errors that I would like to know to be.

**Code HTML:**

```
<div class="ctn">
  <h3>Upload file content ajax</h3>

  <form action="" method="POST" id="form_file" name="form_file" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="imagex" id="imagex">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="btn_form" class="btn btn-primary">Subir imagen</button>

    <div id="mensaje_status"></div>

  </form>

</div><!--End ctn-->
```

**Code AJAX:**

```
$(function() {

    //Empty content alert message
    $('.alert .close').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.alert .msg').html(''); 
    });

    $('#form_file')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                imagex: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Obligatorio!'
                        },
                        file: {
                            extension: 'jpg,jpeg,png',
                            type: 'image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png',
                            //maxSize: 9097152,   // 2048 * 1024
                            message: 'imagen no vÃ¡lida ( JPG, JPEG, PNG ) | Max 9MB'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form    = $(e.target),
                fv       = $form.data('formValidation'),
                formData = new FormData(),
                params   = $form.serializeArray(),
                files    = $form.find('[name="imagex"]')[0].files;

            $.each(params, function (i, val) {
                formData.append(val.name, val.value);
            });

            formData.append('imagex', files[0]);
            formData.append('id', Math.random());

            $.ajax({
                //Star preloader
                xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                            //Convertimos el porcentaje en valor entero
                            var porcentageRound = percentComplete * 100;
                            //Mostramos la ventana modal
                            $('#modal_progress').modal('show');
                            //Limpiamos el Ã¡rea de mensaje en caso de que tenga informaciÃ³n
                            $('#form_file #mensaje_status').html(''); 
                            //Width bar progress
                            $('.progress-bar').css({
                                width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                            });
                            $(".progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' + Math.round(porcentageRound) +' %</div>');
                            //Ocultamos el loader 
                            if (percentComplete === 1) {                     
                              //Podemos manipular los elementos del DOM
                              //Ocultamos la barra de progreso
                              $('.progress').addClass('oculto');
                              //Reseteamos la barra de progreso
                              $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');  
                              //Mostramos un mensaje mientra recibimos respuesta del servidor
                              $('#modal_progress .mensaje').html('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin font20"></i> Procesando espere por favor!');
                            }
                        }
                    }, false);

                    return xhr;
                },
                url: '/upload_ajax_full/do_upload/',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {

                  var data = $.parseJSON(data);

                  if (data.respuesta == true) {
                    //Limpiamos el Ã¡rea de mensaje en caso de que tenga informaciÃ³n
                    $('#form_file #mensaje_status').html('');  
                    //Cerramos la ventana modal
                    $('#modal_progress').modal('hide');
                    //Habilitamos la barra de progreso
                    $('.progress').removeClass('oculto');
                    //Limpiamos mensaje
                    $('#modal_progress .mensaje').html("");
                    //Limpiamos el campo de imagen
                    $('#imagex').replaceWith($('#imagex').clone( true ));
                    //Mostramos mensaje del servidor
                    $('#form_file #mensaje_status').append(data.mensaje);

                  }

                  if (data.respuesta == false) {
                    //Limpiamos el Ã¡rea de mensaje en caso de que tenga informaciÃ³n
                    $('#form_file #mensaje_status').html(''); 
                    //Cerramos la ventana modal
                    $('#modal_progress').modal('hide');
                    //Habilitamos la barra de progreso
                    $('.progress').removeClass('oculto');
                    //Limpiamos mensaje
                    $('#modal_progress .mensaje').html("");
                    //Limpiamos el campo de imagen
                    $('#imagex').replaceWith($('#imagex').clone( true ));
                    //Mostramos mensaje del servidor
                    $('#form_file #mensaje_status').append(data.mensaje);

                  }

                  // You can reset the form if you want
                  fv.resetForm(true);

                  // You can enable the submit button
                  // to allow the user to add new record
                  fv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
                }
            });
        });

});
```

Comment: code would be helpful :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I modified the post, and add the code of a simple example.